# WPF ControlTemplate Setter Stops Working

Tags: wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I have a control template I'm creating for a custom tab control.  Here is the code for the template (MyTabItem just inherits from TabItem and adds an 'Expanded' DependencyProperty that is a bool):

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type graphicElements:MyTabItem}">
    <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" Height="50" UseLayoutRounding="True"  Margin="0,0,-500,0"
                    Effect="{StaticResource EffectDropShadowNoOffset}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="ColExpander" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Column="0" Background="Blue" x:Name="PART_ImageBackground">

        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="1" x:Name="PART_OpacityMask" Background="Transparent">
            <Border Background="Blue" x:Name="PART_MaskScalingBorder">
                <Border.RenderTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0" ScaleY="1" />
                </Border.RenderTransform>
            </Border>
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="Orange" x:Name="PART_ContentBackground">
            <Border.OpacityMask>
                <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=PART_OpacityMask}" />
            </Border.OpacityMask>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" 
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" 
                          ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" 
                          ContentSource="Header" Focusable="False" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                          Margin="15,0" 
                          Grid.Column="1"
                          RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                          IsHitTestVisible="False"
                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                          VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        </Border>
        <Border Background="Transparent" x:Name="PART_HitBackground" />
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Expanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=PART_HitBackground}" Value="True" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25" To="1"
                                         BeginTime="0:0:0.5"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="PART_MaskScalingBorder"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX">
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <QuadraticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25" To="0"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="PART_MaskScalingBorder"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX">
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <QuadraticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
            <Setter TargetName="PART_HitBackground" Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="2" />
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=PART_HitBackground}" Value="False" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="PART_ContentBackground" Value="{StaticResource BrSideMenu}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="PART_ImageBackground" Value="{StaticResource BrSideMenu}" />
            <Setter Property="Effect" TargetName="templateRoot">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <x:Null />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="Expanded" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25" To="1"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="PART_MaskScalingBorder"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX">
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <QuadraticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ColExpander" 
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                                       Duration="0" BeginTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <GridLength>*</GridLength>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="templateRoot" 
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                                       Duration="0" BeginTime="0">
                            <SplineThicknessKeyFrame Value="0" />
                        </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ColExpander" 
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                                       Duration="0" BeginTime="0:0:0.25">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <GridLength>Auto</GridLength>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="templateRoot" 
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                                       Duration="0" BeginTime="0:0:0.25">
                            <SplineThicknessKeyFrame Value="0,0,-500,0" />
                        </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25" To="0"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="PART_MaskScalingBorder"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX">
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <QuadraticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
            <Setter TargetName="PART_HitBackground" Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="2" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

This gets like 95% of what I want to do.  Here is a quick video of it in action:

https://www.screencast.com/t/qNHvJaSo4bp

As you see, when you first start, when you mouse over it give the text flyout which is great.  When I expand it it shows the full items full width, also great.  However once I collapse the panel, the flyouts go away...  Why?  As far as I can see the exit actions set everything back to the way it was before enter actions.  I also don't get any binding errors or anything in VS/Blend when I do it, the flyouts just don't show up.

Can anyone shed any light?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured this out...ish.  I still don't know why it was doing that but but I found a better way to 'skin the cat' that I think is cleaner and actually works fully.

What I ended up doing was splitting the templates.  I created a ControlTemplate for the non-expanded state that has the flyout and required triggers.  Then I created a separate template that is the expanded state that doesn't have the triggers and is basically a simple grid.  Then in the style I created a trigger on the 'Expanded' property and a setter below that changes the control template between the expanded one and the collapsed one depending on the state of the parent.

Note that in my case since the closing is animated, just having it as a setter made the full width section disappear instantly and looked a little funny.  Since you can't (as far as I'm aware) use a storyboard to set a different content template, what I did was in the trigger for the 'Expanded' property I created storyboards and just used a BooleanAnimationUsengKeyFrames to tell it to wait until the close is done to switch templates.

Here are my templates:

Collapsed State

```
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type graphicElements:MyTabItem}" x:Key="CtTabCollapsed">
    <!--Template root with a negative margin allows flyouts to be visible.  Shadow is on grid to allow for multiple inner borders-->
    <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" Height="50" UseLayoutRounding="True"  Margin="0,0,-500,0"
          Effect="{StaticResource EffectDropShadowNoOffset}" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="ColExpander" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!--This border sets the background and holds the image.  No opacity necessary as it is always visible-->
        <Border x:Name="PART_ImageBackground" Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=SelectedColor}">
            <Image Width="32" Height="32" x:Name="PART_Image" Stretch="Uniform" 
               Source="{Binding IconActive, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
        </Border>

        <!--This is the opacity mask that shows or hides the flyout portion-->
        <Border Grid.Column="1" x:Name="PART_OpacityMask" Background="Transparent">
            <!--Outer border is the actual visual to use and is transparent.  Inner border is opaque to show visible portions and is the portion that is scaled-->
            <Border Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=SelectedColor}" x:Name="PART_MaskScalingBorder">
                <Border.RenderTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0" ScaleY="1" />
                </Border.RenderTransform>
            </Border>
        </Border>

        <!--This sets the background and holds the content for the non image portion.  Opacity mask is set by the opacity mask border that resides in the same column-->
        <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=SelectedColor}" x:Name="PART_ContentBackground">
            <Border.OpacityMask>
                <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=PART_OpacityMask}" />
            </Border.OpacityMask>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" 
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" 
                                      ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" 
                                      ContentSource="Header" Focusable="False" 
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                      Margin="15,0" 
                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                                      IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        </Border>

        <!--This is what we use for triggers to determine IsMouseOver.  If we leave it as templated parent it does the whole page and if templateRoot it
                    does the full width even if it's hidden by opacity mask, so we need a separate hit test border here and triggers to make it the right width-->
        <Border Background="Transparent" x:Name="PART_HitBackground" Grid.Column="0" />
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <!--Trigger for expanding the flyout.  Active if not expanded and mouse is over-->
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=PART_HitBackground}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25" To="1"
                                                     BeginTime="0:0:0.5"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="PART_MaskScalingBorder"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX">
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <QuadraticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25" To="0"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="PART_MaskScalingBorder"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX">
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <QuadraticEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            <!--If we expand then the hit test border needs to cover both columns so it doesn't go away when they move the mouse over the text.-->
            <Setter TargetName="PART_HitBackground" Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="2" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <!--Trigger for setting all elements to inactive state if the tab is not selected and the mouse is not over.-->
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=PART_HitBackground}" Value="False" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="PART_ImageBackground" Value="{StaticResource BrSideMenu}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="PART_ContentBackground" Value="{StaticResource BrSideMenu}" />
            <Setter Property="Effect" TargetName="templateRoot">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <x:Null />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter TargetName="PART_Image" Property="Source" Value="{Binding IconInactive,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Expanded State

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type graphicElements:MyTabItem}" x:Key="CtTabExpanded">
    <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" Height="50" UseLayoutRounding="True"  Margin="0"
          Effect="{StaticResource EffectDropShadowNoOffset}"
          Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=SelectedColor}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="ColExpander" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Width="32" Height="32" x:Name="PART_Image" Stretch="Uniform" 
                               Source="{Binding IconActive, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsHitTestVisible="False" />

        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" 
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" 
                                      ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" 
                                      ContentSource="Header" Focusable="False" 
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                      Margin="15,0" 
                          Grid.Column="1"
                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                                      IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                      VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers> 
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <!--Trigger for setting all elements to inactive state if the tab is not selected and the mouse is not over.-->
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=templateRoot}" Value="False" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource BrSideMenu}" />
            <Setter Property="Effect" TargetName="templateRoot">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <x:Null />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter TargetName="PART_Image" Property="Source" Value="{Binding IconInactive,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
        </MultiDataTrigger>            
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And the style

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type graphicElements:MyTabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectedColor" Value="{Binding ApplicationColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=graphicElements:MyTabControl}}" />
    <Setter Property="Expanded" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFACACAC"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource CtTabCollapsed}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSideBarExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=graphicElements:MyTabControl}}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Expanded" BeginTime="0" Duration="0">
                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="True" />
                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Expanded" BeginTime="0:0:0.25" Duration="0">
                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="False" />
                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="Expanded" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource CtTabExpanded}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I won't accept my own answer for a while in case anyone else has a better one but this seems to work.

**EDIT**

Slight modification to this.  As an FYI for anyone else coming along, I found out the storyboards in the styles above don't find their properties if you create a new style based on these.  For how to deal with that see the awesome answer by @Andy on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49947737/style-triggers-dont-inherit).