# Style triggers don't inherit?

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers

I have a style with the following triggers defined:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type graphicElements:MyTabItem}" x:Key="StMyTabItemBase">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectedColor" Value="{Binding ApplicationColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=graphicElements:MyTabControl}}" />
    <Setter Property="Expanded" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFACACAC"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource CtTabCollapsed}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSideBarExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=graphicElements:MyTabControl}}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Expanded" BeginTime="0" Duration="0">
                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="True" />
                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Expanded" BeginTime="0:0:0.25" Duration="0">
                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="False" />
                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="Expanded" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource CtTabExpanded}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This works perfectly when I apply the direct style.  However, I want to be able to create styles based on this style to override specific properties like margins and colors.  I have tried to do so as follows (this creates a default based on this style):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type graphicElements:MyTabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource StMyTabItemBase}" />
```

However, as soon as I do that it no longer triggers or switches the template properly.  If I copy just the triggers into the new style it works again, but I don't want to have to put the triggers into each style individually... Why aren't these inheriting like they are supposed to?  Or do I misunderstand something about BasedOn and Triggers?

**EDIT**

Here is the 'BasedOn' style that works:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type graphicElements:AutodeskTabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource StAutodeskTabItemBase}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSideBarExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=graphicElements:AutodeskTabControl}}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Expanded" BeginTime="0" Duration="0">
                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="True" />
                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Expanded" BeginTime="0:0:0.25" Duration="0">
                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="False" />
                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="Expanded" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource CtTabExpanded}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Basically I just copied out the triggers portion of the base style.  However I don't understand why I have to do that...

Comment: your code is insufficient for the question. what is the target type of the original style, and where is it taking effect?

Comment: Updated to show the full style although I'm not sure it adds much info.  Basically I have a custom class inherited from TabControl that allows the tab panel to be expanded.  Then I have a custom class inherited from TabItem that has an expanded property.  Basically when the tab panel expands it changes the template of the tab items and how they are presented.  Like I said, it works when the style is applied directly but as soon as I do 'BasedOn' to create a new style the triggers don't seem to fire anymore, unless I copy the trigger portion into the new style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about "supposed to" but your exit storyboard definitely won't find the first.
I recently came across this behaviour.  It's an oddity to do with namescope. That won't work.
You could try starting another storyboard targeting the same property with 0 duration and hope that stops it. This did not work in my case.

The way I work round this in my app is to use a multiconverter to start and stop the storyboard.
My converter:

```
public class MultiAnimatorConverter : MarkupExtension, IMultiValueConverter
{
    public Storyboard sb { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // 0 = Shape
        // 1 = Tag
        Shape shape = values[0] as Shape;
        if(shape.Tag.ToString() == "False")
        {
            sb.Stop(shape);
            sb.Remove(shape);
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Begin(shape, true);
        }
        return true;  // Abusing isenabled so I don't need another attached dependency property
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

You may prefer an attached property to enabled.
Useage:

```
<Setter Property="IsEnabled">
    <Setter.Value>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{ui:MultiAnimatorConverter sb={StaticResource MarchinAntsAnimation}}">
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
            <Binding Path="Tag" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

My storyboard is a separate resource.

Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.StrokeDashOffset)" 
            RepeatBehavior="Forever"
            From="0"
            To="8"
            Duration="00:00:.8"
            Timeline.DesiredFrameRate="10"
                                         />

This is used in my Map Editor ( for our game ).  The user is drawing the map for a scenario. They draw terrain. Woods, rivers, contours etc. All are polygons with different templates and I use basedon to inherit so all would get the same "marching ants" animation with dotted lines animated round them when the terrain is selected for editing.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure I follow... won't find the first what?  Wouldn't enter and exit be in the same name scope?  How would enter find it and exit won't?  Sorry I'm fairly new to storyboard animation so I may well be just missing it...

Comment: Wpf names are local to something called a namescope. As the name suggests this is the scope of a name. A template has a namescope which is different for each instance. And the fact there's an inheriting template messes this up. In short your targetname will not work.

Comment: Ok thank you.  I think I see what you are doing.  So in this scenario I would define the storyboards (enter and exit) as an independent resource.  Then using the multi-binding I would basically be setting the values in code, is that correct?  I will give that a go and see if I can get it working...  Thank you for your help, I'll mark as answer if I can get it.

Comment: You, sir, are a genius. THANK YOU!!!  I know the general idea of namescopes but I'm still figuring out what exactly defines a different scope, etc.

Comment: The thing I found particularly odd was running the second storyboard didn't stop my first one. I was convinced that would work. Until I saw the dashes on several of my contours all running round at once. It was funny at first.